# Mathematical Representation of a two column (two channels, or stereo) audio signal

Tags: notation, signal-processing, music-theory

I am a computer science master's student but my experience in converting a code to mathematical operations is very very low. Now I am starting to write the master's thesis as well as writing a paper, and I am in doubt about how could I represent mathematically a two-channel signal audio.

For example:

- Write about ranges from an $i^{th}$ to $j^{th}$
- Or maybe case supposing more ranges in the elements: $i^{th}$ to $j^{th}$ to $n^{th}$ or any of these to $n$: 1 < 1 < j < n
- Doing manipulating operations like: add, remove elements
- Create a zero variable that contains zeros in all elements (zeros(rows, columns) function) for example

I have written the stereo audio signal like $S = f(n) = f_1, f_2,...,f_{n-1},f_n ; g(n) = g_1, g_2,...,g_{n-1},g_n$ where $S$ contains two functions (two channels), and a channel for example where all of the samples are equal zero $S = f(n) = f_1, f_2,...,f_{n-1},f_n = 0 ; g(n) = g_1, g_2,...,g_{n-1},g_n = 0 $. I'm in doubt if this representation is correct or not.

I am basing on this explanation: https://x-engineer.org/graduate-engineering/signals-systems/signal-processing/what-is-a-signal/.

Comment: Ummm... your first "paragraph" is the longest single run-on sentence I've ever read on Math.SE.  Could you do your readers a service and break it into grammatical sentences?  Gosh... even Ben Grossmann (190k) leaves the hodge-podge run-on ungrammatical single sentence!

Comment: I have broken it now in grammatical sentences, check it if it's correct!

Comment: It most certainly is not correct.  "I am a computer science master's student but my experience in converting a code to mathematical operations is very very low, now I am starting to write the master's thesis as well as writing a paper..."  Huh?  You don't think you need a period after "low," to take just the first example?  Bullets or not your whole run-on is STILL a single (ungrammatical) sentence.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: did the problems you had with the OP's use of English prevent you from understanding the mathematical content of the question?

Comment: @RobArthan.  Yes... it did.  What, specifically, did *you* understand by "Or maybe case supposing more ranges in the elements: ℎ to ℎ to ℎ or any of these to : 1 < 1 < j < n," to take just one example?

Comment: From what you have written I cannot figure out what question you are asking. One possible way to clarify it might be to [edit] the question to include carefully written pseudocode with good variable names for  a concept (class or data structure) and an algorithm that uses that concept, and ask for help formulating it in mathematical terms. That _might_ be enough information for us to help you.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: but the OP is asking for help with his use of mathematical language. What I understood was that help (rather than criticism) was being asked for.

Comment: To the OP: I suggest you find a good textbook on signal-processing and try to pick up your terminology from that (and use it as a reference in your thesis). I would hope that you have a teacher who can recommend a good textbook. If you have further problems with the mathematical details, then please post another question here on MSE.

Comment: @RobArthan.  Of *course* help (rather than criticism) is being asked for.  Of course.  But we cannot help (with mathematical language or anything else) if we cannot understand the problem.  That you apparently cannot interpret the problem (as requested) just goes to prove that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: the question is clear in the first paragraph: how to represent a two-channel audio. That probably isn't a good question for MSE, but we shouldn't be hypercritical about non-mathematicians having difficulty explaining their problems.

Comment: @RobArthan:  Actually, I personally think we're *helping* when we point out that a question is unclear.  It is essential an OP know that!  And the issue had little or nothing to do with the OP being a "non-mathematician."  The problems with the ungrammatical paragraph-long "sentence" seemed to have little or nothing to do with math per se.  I teach in an EE department and published a book on sound and audio and *I* didn't clearly understand his question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: i disagree. The OP's problem here is quite clear. Anyway, Snoop has made a start with a useful answer, so I'll leave this to the OP and others.

Comment: I won't drag this out but merely point to my direct question to you (mentioned twice) to interpret a specific part of the problem—quoted verbatim—that you did not (could not?) interpret.  But I'm glad the grammatical problems were pointed out, as there has indeed been some improvement in the question.  Over and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation varies between sources. The most important thing is getting understood. Here are some suggestions.

---

Signals sampled in discrete time are sequences of real numbers of length $N \in \mathbb{N}$. We may write $(x_n)_{n\in \{1,2,3,...,N\}}\subset \mathbb{R}$ if you prefer to start indexing from $1$, but especially if you use Python and do DFTs, it is maybe preferable to write $(x_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}}\subset \mathbb{R}$. This is for univariate sequences.
$$(x_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}}=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_{N-1}\}$$

If the sequence contains $m$ data per sampling instance, then we may write $(x_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}}\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, where $x_n=(x_{1,n},x_{2,n},...,x_{m,n})$, that is, a vector.
$$(x_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}}=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_{N-1}\}=\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,0} \\ x_{2,0} \\ ...\\ x_{m,0}\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,1} \\ x_{2,1} \\ ...\\ x_{m,1}\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,2} \\ x_{2,2} \\ ...\\ x_{m,2}\end{bmatrix},...,\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,N-1} \\ x_{2,N-1} \\ ...\\ x_{m,N-1}\end{bmatrix}\bigg\}$$

If I understood correctly, a two channel would be $m=2$.

---

When selecting a subset of $(x_n)$ from $i$ to $j$, both included (thus length $M=j-i+1$), you can define
$$(y_k)_{k\in \{0,1,...,M-1\}}=\{x_{i},x_{i+1},...,x_{j-1},x_j\}$$
which implies for example $y_1=x_{i+1}$. When you do operations on the sequences, you define new sequences. E.g. adding $1$ to the first element of $(x_n)$
$$(s_n)_{n\in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}}=\{x_0+1,x_1,...,x_{N-1}\}$$

---

When you program, you usually create matrices. If the columns are the sampling times and the rows are the observed elements of sequences, you obtain a $m \times N$ matrix

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,0} & x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & ... & x_{1,N-1} \\ x_{2,0} &x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & ... & x_{2,N-1} \\ ... & ... & ... & ... &...\\ x_{m,0} & x_{m,1} & x_{m,2} & ... & x_{m,N-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

when you code `zeros(rows=m,columns=N)` you create empty matrices:

$$0_{m \times N}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ ... & ... & ... & ... &...\\ 0 & 0& 0 & ... & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

As when with sequences, you create new matrices when you manipulate them and add elements to them.

Comment: Big thanks for the tips Snoop!!! This notation $(x_n)_{n\in \{0,2,3,...,N-1\}}\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ I never saw before and it was new to me especially the \mathbb{R}^m, now it's more clear at the same time that a function can be represented as a set of elements that before I was confusing. The two-channel would be $ n = 2$ (two columns)!

Comment: @Victor columns or rows, it doesn't matter, just be clear when you specify the time indexing and the dimension of the data

Comment: I forgot to ask, to manipulate matrices i.e. add elements/another set on an existing set or eliminate elements inside $({x}_{n})$ it would be valid to use the symbols: $\cup$ or \ also? Knowing that $({x}_{n})$ is a sequence of real numbers (sets)?!

Comment: @Victor when you use matrices, I wouldn't recommend it. When you use sequences to describe the sampled signal, I see how they could be used, but I think they sacrifice clarity in this context (wrt the indexing of the elements)

Comment: Another doubt that came here while I am writing my thesis, could I consider $(x_n)$ as $x(n)$ (already that n would be analogue the $x$ axis and $x(n)$ the $y$ axis)? That I am in doubt if a sequence of real numbers is a function also

Comment: @Victor In general, sequences are functions $x_n:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Here we have finite sequences $x_n:\{0,1,2,...,N-1\} \to \mathbb{R}$, which are still functions because of their indexing